# Redirect non-www to www with Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am serving a static directory like so:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

So I am not using routes at all. I would like to redirect example.com to www.example.com, is this possible using Express?

Comment: While you can certainly do this at the application layer with Express, in most situations you would want to let your web server handle this.  That will help keep the load off your application when it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013098/node-js-www-non-www-redirection

Comment: Hope this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39731460/1946016 worked for you, If so please accept the answer

Answer (score 11):

Yes. This should do it.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express.createServer();
var port = 9090;
app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
  var host = req.header("host");
  if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect(301, "http://www." + host);
  }
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: don't you need to redirect to port 9090 too?

Comment: you need to reverse  your res.redirect args.

Comment: For express 2.x it was `res.redirect = function(url, status){`. It has changed in 3.x to swap the order. I'll update the example. And typically there is a web server listening on port 80 and reverse proxying to express on a different port (9090 in this example), so you don't want to include the 9090 port in your URL. If express was serving directly to the internet, then yes you would need the port if you weren't using the default ports.

Answer (score 11):

The following code preserve path while redirecting

Ex: http://foo.com/foo to http://www.foo.com/foo

```
    var app = express.createServer();
    self.app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
      var host = req.header("host");
      if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect(301, "http://www." + host + req.url);
      }
    });
    app.use('/',express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, has helped me no end. Is there a way to ensure https is preserved at the same time ?

Comment: @Richlewis `res.redirect(301, \`${req.protocol}://www.${host}${req.url}\`);`

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can use a ready-made module for Express that does exactly what you want, e.g. node-force-domain.

See https://github.com/goloroden/node-force-domain for details.

Comment: Let's continue discussing this on GitHub, I have seen that you opened [an issue](https://github.com/goloroden/node-force-domain/issues/1) for that :-)

Comment: Thanks for this module Golo. To me Google analytics was frequently complaining about "Reduntdant Hostnames - To avoid this problem, consider setting up a 301 redirect from one of your redundant hostnames to the other, or create a search-and-replace filter that strips "www." from hostnames.". Your module perfectly solves it. {{moderators google analytics message added intentionally here, it will help fellow coders to find this thread easily}}

Comment: It seems like this works for the root of the website but not for other urls. Is this the expected bahavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can use express-force-domain package from npm:

```
//install
npm install express-force-domain

///app.js
app.all('*', require('./express-force-domain')('http://www.example.com') );
```

Package on npm: https://npmjs.org/package/express-force-domain

Comment: this solution works very well, even for http to https