# Problems authenticating with Reddit OAuth in 'www' subdomain

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, reddit

I currently have Reddit authorization set up for my Node app just like in [this example](https://github.com/Slotos/passport-reddit/blob/master/examples/login/app.js). I have the app on Reddit setup for the callback url `http://example.com/auth/reddit/callback` and everything is fine. Users can enter `http://example.com/auth/reddit` and log in and everything is good.

The problem comes in when a user tries to log in through `http://www.example.com/`. It appears that Reddit's CSRF protection sees these requests as an issue. As per the example:

```
/**
 * Authentication route
 */
app.get('/auth/reddit', function(req, res, next) {
    var n = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    req.session.state = n;
    passport.authenticate('reddit', {
        state    : n,
        duration : 'permanent'
    })(req, res, next);
});

/**
 * Authentication callback
 */
app.get('/auth/reddit/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    // Check for origin via state token
    if (req.query.state === req.session.state) {
        /* authenticate the user */
    } else { next(new Error(403)); }
}
```

For requests from `http://example.com/auth/reddit`, `req.query.state === req.session.state`. However, for requests made from `http://www.example.com/auth/reddit`, these values do not match. `req.query.state` takes the new state value, but `req.session.state` retains an old state value.

Is there a good work-around or solution to this problem? One work-around could be to automatically redirect all 'www' request to the root, but I haven't found a way to do that. Another option would be to remove the state check, but this would open up my code to CSRF attacks. Leaving everything as-is is not an option, as to users it's (understandably) very counter-intuitive to have the root domain work but the 'www' subdomain not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I'm using the node.js package `express-force-domain`

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12755464/1222411

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, reddit redirects the user back to non-www domain, as per reddit application setup, and thus your session data is not available to you.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Configure cookies to use `.mydomain.com`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887384/472104) for details.
2. Ignore state flag, since it's not mandatory in OAuth2 spec, albeit recommended. Example has it for one simple reason, reddit fails to process a request if state field is not present. At least is was the case when I was writing the library. You are free to send any random string as a state value without checking for it on return.

I'd personally recommend the first approach as a default one, since state flag is designed to prevents [a certain type of attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20187/oauth2-cross-site-request-forgery-and-state-parameter). You might want to go with second approach for simplicity, but do so only if you're well informed of potential consequences - which might strip it of the simplicity value.