# app creating two sessions for same user - express js

Tags: node.js, express

My app is creating two sessions for a user dependent on whether the user types the url with a www prefix or not.
Is this something I should/can deal with in express, or should I look to normalize the url higher in my stack?

any pointers much appreciated,

Comment: just redirect all `www.*` urls to one without `www` or vice versa.

Comment: thanks Johnathan, is there a global way to do this in express?

Comment: found it - thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013098/node-js-www-non-www-redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend redirecting all www.* urls to one without www or vice versa. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013098/node-js-www-non-www-redirection) or if you are using a forward proxy like Nginx you could use that instead.