# NodeJS Redirect all non-www to www except subdomains

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, express, no-www

any idea on how i can do this in Express 3.0? As the non-www url is causing very odd problems in different areas of the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i found the answer from another question.

[Node.js: 301 redirect non-www without express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898183/node-js-301-redirect-non-www-without-express)

Sorry for not searching before

```
app.get ('/*', function (req, res, next){
  if (!req.headers.host.match(/^www\./)){
      res.writeHead (301, {'Location': 'http://mysite.com'});
  }else{ 
     return next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer didn't work for me.
I've used the following code (http://redirect-www.org/#nodejs):

```
//REDIRECT www.domain.com TO domain.com
app.get ('/*', function (req, res, next){
    var protocol = 'http' + (req.connection.encrypted ? 's' : '') + '://'
      , host = req.headers.host
      , href
      ;

    // no www. present, nothing to do here
    if (!/^www\./i.test(host)) {
      next();
      return;
    }

    // remove www.
    host = host.replace(/^www\./i, '');
    href = protocol + host + req.url;
    res.statusCode = 301;
    res.setHeader('Location', href);
    res.write('Redirecting to ' + host + req.url + '');
    res.end();
});
```

**Care**: this will redirect www to non-www, if you want the opposite, delete the `not` on the `if` condition and then replace `host = host.replace(/^www\./i, '');` with `host = 'www.' + host;`