# Redirect from http to https in google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssl

I have deployed a site on google cloud on Nodejs environment. I want to redirect the user from http to https as i want to make https as default.
I have already attached SSL certificate with my custom domain in App engine and it is working fine.
I also tried to redirect to https from node but none is working on google cloud.

I am having less knowledge of cloud if things did not work then i have to migrate to Heroku.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/42991054/1128918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setup it in your `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IGNORED
  secure: always
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#security

Comment: Thanks Igor for help, I am stuck in somewhere i want to redirect all my request to naked domain like (https://www.example.com) to (https://example.com) , Can it be done from node end , i found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473222/nodejs-redirect-all-non-www-to-www-except-subdomains

Comment: I believe it's much easier to configure this on domain registrator panel, many of them are providing such feature for free

Comment: Thanks Igor for help but domain registrar does not work for me, so i redirected all calls to www subdomain using node code.

Comment: yes, if DNS is already configured, then it's possible to do on server, likes it's done in mentioned post

Comment: I got this error testing this code:
Unexpected attribute 'secure' for object of type AppInfoExternal.

Comment: It seems like `handlers` are ignored for Node apps.