# Http Requests not getting routed to Https NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, https, google-cloud-platform

I have my Server on `Google App Engine` and I am using npm module [yes-https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yes-https), below is the code I am writing in order to restrict the requests to Https.

```
app.use(yes({
   maxAge: 86400,            // defaults `86400`
   includeSubdomains: true,  // defaults `true`
   preload: true             // defaults `true`           
}));
```

Previously this code was working fine and all my requests whether `Https` OR `Http` all were getting routed to `Https`. But now I don't know why requests coming to Http is not getting routed to Https.

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello actually this plugin is working perfectly fine. The mistake I was doing was I was putting `yes-https` on the `middleware` after the setting the `/public` directory, but the right way was to put it before setting `/public` directory.

**Right Code**

```
app.use(yes({
  maxAge: 86400,            // defaults `86400`
  includeSubdomains: true,  // defaults `true`
  preload: true             // defaults `true`           
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

**Wrong Code**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(yes({
  maxAge: 86400,            // defaults `86400`
  includeSubdomains: true,  // defaults `true`
  preload: true             // defaults `true`           
}));
```

Because of which `Https` was not enforcing but now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Sudhanshu, can you please show me where this code would go in a React app on Google App Engine? I don't understand how this fits in to that environment. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh I didn't get you, this code is for server-side only, so what React has to do with it, maybe specifying yes-https middleware before all other's will work ?