# Google App Engine - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to app engine and I'm trying to set it up so that any http requests get redirected to https.

My app.yaml file looks like this. I have script: None in there because if I don't have it there I get some parsing error, but that's not the problem.

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: None
  secure: always
```

So right now, if I go to http :// mysite.org it stays on the http version and just shows 'mysite.net' in the url bar. If I go to https :// mysite.org it shows the secured version. If I go to the appspot url that google gave me, the http redirects to the https version just fine. Is there something I'm missing in the app.yaml? This isnt in a custom runtime

Comment: I think `None` is the problem.  Try fixing your code so you can add a script there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL on App Engine Flexible Environment Custom Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944776/force-ssl-on-app-engine-flexible-environment-custom-runtime)

Comment: Apparently the Flex environment doesn't support handlers. See [Justin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777860/http-to-https-redirection-on-app-engine) for more information and a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`helmet`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/), `secure` setting under `handlers` in `app.yaml` is **depricated** in the Google App Engine Latest Release.

https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/

https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html

```
// Forcing HTTPS connections on Gooogle App Engine Flexible Environment sample app.js

'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(helmet.hsts({
    maxAge: 31536000,
    includeSubDomains: true,
    preload: true,
    setIf: function (req, res) {
        return req.secure;
    }
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.secure) {
        res.redirect(301, "https://" + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl);
    }
    res.status(200).send("hello, world\n").end();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

> **Upgrading to the App Engine Latest Release**
>
> The `secure` setting under `handlers` is now deprecated for the App Engine flexible environment. If you need SSL redirection, you can update your application code and use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to redirect `http` traffic.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/upgrading#appyaml_changes

> **Forcing HTTPS connections**
>
> For security reasons, all applications should encourage clients to connect over https. You can use the Strict-Transport-Security header to instruct the browser to prefer https over http for a given page or an entire domain, for example:
>
> `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/how-requests-are-handled

> **HTTPS and forwarding proxies**
>
> With Express.js, use the trust proxy setting
>
> `app.set('trust proxy', true);`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code snippet below to [web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml) works just fine on Flexible environment

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```