# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Google App Engine Flexible in PHP7 Environment?

Tags: php, app-engine-flexible, app.yaml, google-app-engine-php, http-redirect

According to Google docs I added the following to app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

After app's deployment when I enter http://example.com no redirection to https://example.com occurs. My custom domain is verified by Google and SSL is set to Google's auto-managed feature. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you updated the DNS records?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update

Answer (score 0):

Handlers in app.yaml were deprecated in the Google App Engine Flexible environment.

You need to [force HTTPS connection](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections) according to the guide to make the browser use `https` instead of `http` by using the [HTTP Strict Transport Security response header](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Example:
`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`

Another option is to use the custom HTTP header `X-Forwarded-Proto` to redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

Below is a similar issue.

- [Google App Engine - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024061/google-app-engine-redirect-http-to-https)