# In NodeJS + Express, how to automatically remove URL 'www'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, dns

In NodeJS + Express, how to automatically remove URL 'www'?
for example,
client connect to https://www.stackoverflow.com
then, https://stackoverflow.com connected!
how to automatically remove URL 'www'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753761 checkout this answer. There’s instructions after the code for making it remove the www instead of adding it.

Comment: http://redirect-www.org/#nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below middleware right somewhere in beginning.

```
var wwwRedirect = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.get('host').indexOf('www.') === 0){
      if(req.method === "GET" && !req.xhr){
        return res.redirect(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host').substring(4) + req.originalUrl);
      }
    }
  }
  next();
};

app.use(wwwRedirect);
```