# Server side redirect in backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, server-side

I have model object:

```
module.exports = {
 redirectTo: function(params, callback) {
  callback(null, 'home/redirect_to');
 }
}
```

Can I redirect user without loading page?

It will depend on variables, so redirecting not always needed. The only thing I need now is redirecting from server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `this.redirectTo(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Server side redirection can be done by simply replying [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to client.

If what you are asking is "How to go around server side redirection so that your Backbone callback can still be triggered?", then my solution will be following:

For example, when an user type a url `http://yousite.com/blog/someid` on his browser, and you want to use Backbone callback to handle his request. Then you can let your server return:

```
<script> window.location="http://yoursite.com#blog/someid"</script>
```

Note we replace a `/` into `#`.

Or, you can let your server return ([fragment allowed in Location](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/6)):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://yoursite.com#blog/someid
```

Then your Backbone callback will be triggered.

Comment: I will detect rather redirect to an url or not. If yes, I need to return 302 (or 301) redirect to user. So, How I can return 302 redirection in controller?

Comment: @EminMastizada So you are asking how to return 302 in server side controller (`NodeJS`)? Here's a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: thanks for all, I tried this.redirectTo() and it worked.