# Nodejs redirect url to tomcat server

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, http-redirect

To solve CORS issue, I need remove my server port and use apache to redirect to my tomcat with port.

example: http get url: `localhost/app1/somerequest`,  my apache server will redirect to `localhost:8080/app1/somerequest`, so how can this redirect be work when i use **nodejs**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *proxy* the request, use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).
If you want to *redirect* the request, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)