# Redirect user to previous page after authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Google auth through Passport in my app and I'm attempting to redirect the user back to the original page they requested after successful sign-in. I think that `location.reload()` may be the problem, but not sure how to solve it.

routes.js:

```
router.post('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google'), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(req.session.returnTo);
  req.session.returnTo = null;
});
```

middleware.js:

```
var isAuth = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    req.session.returnTo = req.url;
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
};
```

called on button click:

```
$.post('/auth/google/return', {code: authResult.code, access_token: authResult.access_token}).done(function(data) {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: please check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url

Comment: location is not native JavaScript method

Comment: ajax requests don't play very well with server-side redirects. the redirect will have to happen client-side, or, you can remove the ajax request (probably the better option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
router.post('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google'), function(req, res) {
   var backURL = req.header('Referer') || '/';
   res.json({redir: backURL});
});
```

And:

```
$.post('/auth/google/return', {code: authResult.code, access_token: authResult.access_token}).done(function(data) {
    window.location.href = data.redir;
});
```

Comment: When I look in the console that seems to have worked, as the correct page was loaded behind the scenes. Yet the actual page never updates. Strange.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that results in 'Cannot GET /undefined'.

Comment: What's interesting is that when I `console.log(data)` in place of `window.location.href = data.redir` I see all the HTML of the page I was hoping to see. Could this be because I'm using Jade to serve my HTML files?

Comment: did you change the Node part too with this `res.json({redir: backURL});`?

Comment: the idea is to send the url string in json to the post response and use that to window.location.href