# How to handle angular2 route path in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a NodeJS app with Angular2. In my app, I have a home page and search page. For home page I have an HTML page that will render for the **localhost:3000/** and from home page user navigate to **search** i.e **localhost:3000/search**  page that I handled by **angular2 routes**.

I don't have the page for the search page its view render by the angular2. But when I directly hit **localhost:3000/search** as I don't have this routing in my node app it gives the error.

I don't know How to handle this in node app?

Comment: You should use angular2 routing using path after # as localhost:3000/#/search. This way angular 2 will get the request, not the server

Comment: but angular2 generate the route without  #

Comment: Configure your server to redirect to your start page. After quick search I [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: but in my case  its not the 404 request if i do this its just render home page for instead of search page and for 404 request also

Comment: My bad, I meant to say _you need to configure server to return your start page (index.html usually) if it can't find requested uri_... I don't know how to do that in node, I'm using other servers (`.htaccess` for php, middleware for local server, routes in python...), but hopefully this can lead you to the right answer...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you enter `localhost:3000/search` directly in the browser navigation bar, your browser issues an request to '/search' to your server, which can be seen in the console (make sure you check the 'Preserve Log' button).

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/search
```

If you run a fully static server, this generates an error, as the search page does not exist on the server. Using express, for example, you can catch these requests and returns the index.html file. The angular2 bootstrap kicks-in, and the /search route described in your @RouteConfig is activated.

```
// example of express()
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(static_dir));

// Additional web services goes here
...

// 404 catch 
app.all('*', (req: any, res: any) => {
  console.log(`[TRACE] Server 404 request: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(200).sendFile(index_file);
});
```

Comment: then how do i handle if there is any 404 request

Comment: With @RouteConfig like this: 
  @RouteConfig([
    { path: '' ,            component: HomeCmp,    name: 'HomeCmp' },
    { path: 'search' , component: SeachCmp,    name: 'SearchCmp' },
    { path: 'error',     component: ErrorCmp,      name: 'ErrorCmp' },
    { path: '**',          redirectTo: ['ErrorCmp']       }
  ])

Comment: Great answer. Also, if you aren't using TypeScript, it might be something like `app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HashLocationStrategy

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "angular2/router";
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
 ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

In your bootstrap file.

If you want to go with PathLocationStrategy ( without # ) you must setup rewrite strategy for your server.

Comment: provide is import from ??

Comment: import { provide } from "angular2/core"; ah sorry

Comment: can you please give some more  details for the :
If i want to go with PathLocationStrategy ( without # ) what i   setup rewrite strategy for my server

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging this topic for quite a time , and try a lot of method that don' work . 
If you are using angular-cli and with express , I found a solution if the chosen answer doesn't works for you .

Try this node module : [express-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback)

[ Angular ] Change your app.module.ts file , under @NgModule > imports as following :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes), ...
```

This is so called : " Location Strategy "

You probably were using " Hash Location Strategy " like this :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) , ...
```

[ Express & Node ]
Basically you have to handle the URL properly , so if you want call "api/datas" etc. that doesn't conflict with the HTML5 Location Strategy .

In your server.js file ( if you used express generator , I've rename it as middleware.js for clarity )

Step 1.  - Require the express-history-api-fallback module.

```
const fallback = require('express-history-api-fallback');
```

Step 2 . You may have a lot of routes module , sth. like :

```
app.use('/api/users, userRoutes);
app.use('/api/books, bookRoutes); ......
app.use('/', index); // Where you render your Angular 4 (dist/index.html)
```

Becareful with the order you are writing , in my case I call the module right under app.use('/',index);

```
app.use(fallback(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
```

* Make sure it is before where you handle 404 or sth. like that .

This approach works for me : ) 
I am using EAN stack (Angular4 with cli , Express , Node )