# How to integrate ExpressJS server with Angular2

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I try to create an angular2 app with NodeJS (Express) as a server. 
The problem is that there is a conflict as Express tries to use its own template engine, and route the requests, while angular also uses routes and index.html as the entry point.

How can I integrate both?

Comment: An angular2 project set up and running, but I am afraid that if I create the Express server it will override the file structure. I couldn't find a decent reference how to solve it

Comment: Does this solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34864585/2112228

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically, NodeJS/Express would be used to serve an API with endpoints that Angular can consume. NodeJS would be a backend only, Angular would be a frontend only.

While Angular *can* be served from a NodeJS server, it's a waste of resources since most Angular sites are totally static. That is, they're javascript, CSS and images that could be served from S3 or an FTP and get all their dynamic content via services (tweets from twitter, images from an S3 bucket, data from your custom NodeJS backend, etc.). In other words, no dynamic server side rendering required.

I would strongly recommend maintaining this approach. Host your Angular app on a static storage host like S3 and create a REST API using NodeJS which your app can talk through via Angular services. Send `GET` requests to fetch JSON data. Take the resulting JSON data and use it to populate your app. Send `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests to add or manipulate data (assuming you plan to have a backend database).

The way this is usually represented on your domain would be to have `http://yourdomain.com` point to your Angular app. Your angular app would then make calls to `http://yourdomain.com/api/` or `http://api.yourdomain.com` which are pointed at your Node API. You can configure your DNS to do either of these **without** the need for physical subdirectories in your code.

Comment: But do I have to split their locations? what if I want them to run from the same parent directory/project?

Comment: You can host them on different places but configure your DNS so they host from what appears to be the same domain. I'd strongly advise against trying to mix backend and frontend code in a single codebase.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include more info about typical hosting setups.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation - I am glad I did not run into solving collisions with Angular/Express. In any case is it recommended the servers physically?

Comment: The implementation is up to you but a good solution would be to host your angular app on S3 and your NodeJS API on a service like Heroku. Then just configure your DNS in front of both.