# Angular 2 - Remove Hash (#) from the URL

Tags: angular2-routing

I am loading the modules by `loadChildren("123#childModule")` from `appModule` and it is always appending `/#/` in the browser.

I have tried `useHash : false` as well as `Providers` as `PathLocationStrategy`, but I still see the issue.

Been doing research on this but I did not find any solution so far. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Syntax enhanced

Comment: Add your app.routing.ts module contents here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315140/2978923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try for this:

If you are using Angular final, the reasons to the hash could be:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutesHere, { useHash: true })
```

or Use this:

Beside the module providers, check your module imports, it can also be overridden by providing the  { useHash: true } as the second argument of the RouterModule.forRoot:

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // remove second argument
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you were trying lazyloading with module 
The routes code should be like this :

```
{ path: 'mgt', loadChildren: 'app/your-mgt/your-mgt.module#YourModule'}
```

And the # shows on your url have nothing to do with the "#" here .
By default , Angular used PathLocationStrategy already

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

I guess this is yours :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true } or RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false }
```

Not sure whats your backend is , but if you have one , and it will use ajax to fetch data .
If you are using Express in your backend . 
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749975/6489009)

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks for your response. we are seeing the /#/ in the url on just loading the static page itself with no service calls. tried useHash: false but still no luck. we are not sure what exactly is adding # in the url. i am pretty new to angular 2, please help.

Comment: I figured out where it is going wrong, the custom libraries that we made are using Hashlocation strategy. thanks for your support and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash:false} );
```

Or remove useHash :

```
RouterModule.forRoot( appRoutes );
```