# React App not starting in azure app service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I've deployed a simple react app to azure app service and it won't start:

How do I get the app to run index.html?

[image]

Comment: No I'm not running anything, isnt that what app service is supposed to do, serve index files by default?

Comment: it should just run it, thats right. what are you getting instead?

Comment: Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: If you're using `react-router`, Azure App Service Linux Host uses an HTTP server to proxy your code to the web. You need to set up URL re-write rules. You do this because if you have a `react-router` url (`/about`), when a user refreshes the page, the HTTP server will try to load a file called `/about`, but that files doesn't exist, which will result in a 404 error. The URL re-write rules will change this behavior. It will instead load `index.html`, `/about` will show the correct page from `react-router`. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306811/1913185) to the answer.

Comment: Sure but the app doesn't load at all.

Comment: How are you deploying? git? ftp?

Comment: Azure Repos git

Answer (score 36, accepted):

add this command in your azure dashboard > Configuration > Startup Command

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon`

and restart your server. This fixed it for me!

Comment: how do we pass `--proxy-config proxy.conf.json` with pm2?

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to install express and configure index.js as mentioned in other answers since that needs config change and not sure whether app scaling event will retain those installations in new instance.

Easy way is to use pm2 since that is already part of stack. Pass the below startup command for the app

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon
```

Once we restart, it should pick the pages from the docroot (/home/site/wwwroot)

Comment: how do we pass `--proxy-config proxy.config.json` with pm2?

Answer (score 14):

**Go to Azure Configuration>General Settings**

- If your `build` folder is at the root of the project

Start up command: `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`

- If your `build` folder is inside your client folder, just add the path

Start up command: `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/client/build --no-daemon --spa`

---

Note:

*Make sure your using Azure App Service `linux` server.*

*I added `--spa` at the end to fix the issue of react-router redirect, Using `--spa` will automatically redirect all queries to the index.html and then react-router will do its magic.*

Comment: how do we pass `--proxy-config proxy.conf.json` with pm2?

Answer (score 5):

If you deployed to a Node Linux Web App the default document would be `hostingstart.html` located in `/home/site/wwwroot/`.

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NodeHome):

> When you create a Node.js app, by default, it's going to use
>   hostingstart.html as the default document unless you configure it to
>   look for a different file. You can use a JavaScript file to configure
>   your default document. Create a file called index.js in the root
>   folder of your site

So go to your ssh terminal, navigate to `/home/site/wwwroot`. Create index.js there with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**NOTE**: Be sure to run npm install --save express also in this folder else your app service will crash on startup

Restart, it will configure index.html as the default document for your app.

Comment: When I add those express scripts to my existing index.js file, and run locally I get an error. The app runs fine locally so won't this conflict?

Comment: @Batman, I test and get error then install the express module then it worked. You could have a try.`$ npm install express`

Comment: I've been two days nonstop setting up my CICD pipelines in az devops and the issue ended up being: the main file has to be named `hostingstart.html`. @Satheesh [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310584/5212904) worked for me.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I have a similar issue and posted my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245335/create-react-app-with-express-on-azure-app-service-fails-to-start. Could you please take a look at that. I've been working for the last couple of days & keep getting the `module express not found` error. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So thanks to Burke Holland. The easiest is to create a build folder running

```
npm run build
```

Then you copy your build folder into your destination and add a "ecosystem.config.js" file.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: "npx serve -s"
    }
  ]
};
```

See this link for more information:
https://burkeknowswords.com/this-is-how-to-easily-deploy-a-static-site-to-azure-96c77f0301ff

Note: This works for a deployment to a Node Linux App Service instance in Azure. No client side routing configuration needed with this approach!

For Windows App service you can create a config file for  configuring your client side routing.

Comment: this solution took care of both issues, starting the react app and handling react-router issues.