# Equivalent of window.location and window.pathname in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the equivalent to `window.location.protocol` and `window.location.host` in NodeJS/ExpressJS?

I'm trying to redirect the url back to my site using a third party API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs - Redirect url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NodeJS API [url.format(urlObject)](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobject) method returns a formatted URL string derived from `urlObject`.

```
var url = require('url');

function getFormattedUrl(req) {
    return url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.get('host')
    });
}

res.redirect(getFormattedUrl(req));
```

Comment: Isn't getting the **host** name from the **Host** headers secure? @YosvelQuinteroArguelles [Check this one](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-implement-password-reset-feature-in-a-web-application.htm#-be-careful-when-cre)