# access to firebase functions environment variables in another proejct

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have three different cloud-function projects and each project contains unique function and environment variables associated with them. Is there a way to have access to environment variables setup in project 'A', while function in project 'B' is being executed?

Say functions.config().user.name="mike" is setup in project 'A' and I want to have access to that user variable when invoking function in project 'B'.

All projects are under the same firebase account but in separate projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are deployed per-function.  There's no mechanism provided to allow a function to reach into another function's configuration.

If you want to share data between functions, consider simply writing that data to a database or some other cloud-based storage system that's accessible to both.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. by using firebase-admin and service accounts of each project, I thought that I could have access to any env variables in different projects under the same account. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46023340/11015504

Comment: You deploy multiple functions in a single project with the same variables, but they are actually each isolated from each other.