# How would I redirect the client to another page upon auth?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the code I run once a user clicks the Sign In button:

```
 app.post('/api/sign-in', function(req, res, next) {
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(function (user) {
console.log('a new user has signed in! their e-mail address: '+user.email+' | User ID: '+user.uid)
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log(error)
})
})
```

What would be the appropriate way of 'transferring' the user to another page (for example, members area)? Would I stick that code in the callback method?

Answer (score 0):

Your node server should probably return the auth token to the client, then the client handles the direct, probably using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Though you could also [return a 302 status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url).