# VueJS: Redirecting URL to SPA Routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently working the first time with vue-router and I am wondering if there is a way to handle redirecting through vue or if there are other options in a node.js environment to do so.

For example, if someone wants to visit my site through typing the URL

```
example.com/contact
```

he will currently get to

```
example.com/contact#/home
```

But of course I want to redirect to the correct path.

Comment: If you want it to catch it before the actual SPA entry point has been accessed and a client service worker can be loaded, you need to do it server side.
If it is a node server this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Otherwise it is done by editing .htaccess for Apache or web.config for IIS

Comment: If you mean to redirect to different URLs within your Vue application, with vue-router you can use `router.push()` (see [navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)) or the `redirect` directive inside the router configuration (see [Redirect](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html)). If you want to navigate to a totally different URL, you could change [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Otherwise, if you want it to take place before the app has taken control, you have to do it from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

The first one is to keep using hash router, which means that you will have to add a hashtag before the path so the correct url would be example.com#/contact. Hash router has the benefit that it works with your web server out of the box without any other configuration.

Another option is to switch to [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) on the Vue router. History mode lets you have URLs without the hashtag, however there's a drawback that it doesn't work with most web servers without separate configuration. The link above includes the necessary configurations for many web servers, where you will need to add it somewhere depending on the web server.