# How redirect url to www in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I redirect my url to www?

For example:
https://myurl.com ---> https://www.myurl.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs - Redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: @JonasLochmann For light duty you can do this in Node.js just fine. The server-level redirect only matters if your Node app can't keep up.

Comment: @CodyG. A `CNAME` record won't redirect.

Comment: Alternatively... use a DNS subdomain forward... I don't know what I was thinking before...

Comment: @CodyG. DNS can be a little confusing, especially on a Friday.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Express, then check [req.hostname](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname) - if the hostname doesn't start with "www" then you will want to [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) with a 301 (permanently moved) or 302 (temporarily moved) HTTP status, pointing to the new URL with "www" in it.