# Programmatically altering address in Node.js on server side

Tags: node.js, backend

I have always wondered how can I do this..

if you go https://community.nodebb.org/topic/14103/strange-thing-on-this-forum

It shows a thread in a forum.

But you can actually access to that same page with https://community.nodebb.org/topic/14103

and then this url changes to the 1st one above.

How can I do this in Node.js?

Comment: Looks like a redirect... add a response [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062281/10431732) on the route you want to redirect, voila. NOTE: the route you are redirecting to must be an active/available route..(obviously).. EDIT2: [Or if you are using Express..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038048/10431732)

Comment: Are you familiar with what happens when a web server returns a [301 Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) status code?  It's called _URL redirection_.  Or do you need source code for a particular framework in Node.js?  What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node itself is just the language, what you're asking about happens in a framework, like Express.
In Express (and most other frameworks) you can define routes based on either strings, symbols, or a regex. In your above example, the route definition is likely looking for `topic/:id` and also set to accept anything put after the ID.
Look at the basics of [Routing in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) to see how this works.

Comment: Your wrong, You do need node to do this, express just uses node in order to accomplish that.
you can do it easily by urself(Ive done it, built a small light moudle who route)