# how to i get my vendor(connected account) to the stripe payout page after we onboard them?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

how to i direct my vendor to this stripe payout page after I onboard them use the account API?

we are a marketplace with many vendor. i wanted to create a button on the vendor(connected account) page and when they click on the button on our dashboard. it goes to the vendor stripe page but I just cant get the connect account URL for the vendor.

```
return stripe.accountLinks.create({
  type: "account_onboarding",
  account: accountID,
  refresh_url: `${origin}/`,
  return_url: `${origin}/`,
});
```

example link:
https://connect.stripe.com/express/m7ucEu2cZPbD

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your web server, but you'd just redirect the user when you're ready.

For instance, in express you'd do something like:

```
const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
  type: "account_onboarding",
  account: accountID,
  refresh_url: `${origin}/`,
  return_url: `${origin}/`,
});

res.redirect(accountLink.url);
```

There's more examples with other Node frameworks here: [Nodejs - Redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: how do i get the url account page of the vendor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by vendor here. Do you mean connected account? If so you can use the Stripe-Account header to make requests on behalf of a connected account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts

Comment: we are a marketplace with many vendor. i wanted to ceate a button on the vendor(connected account) page and when they click on the button on our dashboard. it goes to the vendor stripe page but I just cant get the connect account URL for the vendor.